# Reuse export.function in same document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am building a settings module in a mean.js stack. And I want to re-use an existing function. But how? Here is some demo code:

```js
controller-x.js

var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ),
    errorHandler = require( './errors' ),
    time = require( 'time' ),
    _ = require( 'lodash' );


exports.create = function( req, res ) {
    // create something
};


exports.save = function( req, res ) {
    // save something
};

exports.update = function( req, res ) {
    // update something
};
```

How can i (re-)use the "save" function in the update or create, or some another function?

Comment: re-use how exactly? You could always create the function at the top, and just reference it `exports.save = fn;` and then call it other places `fn()`, but why ?

Comment: Ahh man. He beat me to it :(

Comment: @adeneo he wouldn't even have to create the function at the top. Anywhere in the file would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the function elsewhere in the code, and simply reference it when the `exports.save` function is called, like this:

```
var someFunction = function(req, res) {
  ...logic for your save function...
};

exports.save = someFunction(req, res);

exports.update = function(req, res) {
  someFunction(req, res);
  ... And whatever other logic you want to use...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a private method:

```
controller-x.js

var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ),
    errorHandler = require( './errors' ),
    time = require( 'time' ),
    _ = require( 'lodash' );

var save = function( req, res ) {
    // save something
};   

exports.create = function( req, res ) {
    // create something
    save();
};


exports.save = save;

exports.update = function( req, res ) {
    // update something
};
```